# Should we remove the toxic-people tag? (removed tag)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [toxic-people](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toxic-people) tag is presently used by 5 questions, of which 4 are closed and 1 is likely to be closed soon. This tag does not seem particularly useful, as it would mostly be used by questions aimed at complaining about coworkers. Should we remove this tag?

**Update**: Based on the community consensus (+9/0 on question, +16/0 on Walfrat's answer), I have removed this tag from all the questions that were using it. [It will get removed automatically at 03:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/202356).

Comment: Seems like a silly tag to me. I would nuke it.

Comment: *Let's not go there, tis a silly place*, cloppity, cloppity, clop

Comment: @Draken it's only a model.

Comment: Most of the questions can be retagged easily enough...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm in favor to nuke because :

1. there are already the tags work-environment, professionalism and unprofessional-behavior to describe this problem
2. such a tag don't seems itself to be profesional and calling people toxic here would not pass the Be nice policy.

Comment: I agree.  A tag like that just encourages gossip.